# How to modify headers of WebMVC.fn RouterFunction response?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've defined a `RouterFunction` bean, with handler function returning a response with string body, which is a JSON. The builder however sets the content type to `text/plain` on passing a string to `body`

```java
ServerResponse.ok().body(responseString).build() // Content type set to text/plain
```

```java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> infoRouter(MyHandler myHandler) {
    return nest(
            path("info"),
            route().GET("definitions", __ -> myHandler.getDefinitions()).build()
    ).filter(HandlerFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor((serverRequest, serverResponse) ->
            // TODO: Set content type header to application/json
    ));
}
```

I tried to clone the response using `ServerResponse::from` but it doesn't include the response body. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Set it properly in your handler function. Something like `ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(whatever you like)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum There are multiple handler functions. I was hoping it were possible to set it for all of them through a filter instead of having to specify it each time.

Comment: Is there a reason you are returning a `String` instead of just objects which get converted to JSON and that way the correct content type is set?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have some nested DTOs, from which I need to remove nulls at every level, so I am using a custom instance of `ObjectMapper` configured to do that. But I couldn't figure out a simple way of telling `RouterFunction` to use that custom instance, so I'm manually using `ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString` on the object before passing it to `ServerResponse.BodyBuilder::body`

Comment: You can configure WebFlux to use your custom configured `ObjectMapper` or just configure the global one to leave out the `null` values.